# Is it possible to update ng-repeat at responsive breakpoints?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, responsive-design, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is it possible to have Angular update an ng-repeat at particular screen-sizes?

I have 20 divs, however at 640px and below I would like to display only 6, between 640px 1024px I would like to display 15 and greater than 1024px I would like to display all 20.

As I mentioned I am using ng-repeat to rollout the divs and I would like to be able to reinit?? (not sure if that is the right term, I am learning) the ng-repeat function when the browser hits one of those sizes. The ng-repeat would be updated with the amount of items needed to roll out and would then roll them out.

This is how I have the ng-repeat set up:

```
.articles(ng-controller="articlesCtrl")
  .article(ng-repeat="article in articles | limitTo:15", class='item-{{ $index + 1 }}')
```

Comment: You might try this: set `limitTo: someValue`, then update this value from directive that calculates how many should be visible...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand? I have only stared learning AngularJS in the last month so I'm still finding my feet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sasxa was saying, declare a scope variable like "myScopeVar" or "someValue"

JS - in your controller

```
$scope.numDisp = 6;
// based on screen width, but you can base on height as well http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_screen.asp
if(window.screen.width < 641)
    $scope.numDisp = 6; // 
else if(window.screen.width > 640 && window.screen.width < 1025)
    $scope.numDisp = 15
else if(window.screen.width > 1024)
    $scope.numDisp = 20
```

HTML:

```
.article(ng-repeat="article in articles | limitTo: numDisp", class='item-{{ $index + 1 }}')
```

Update

I looked at your plunker and noticed that you should be firing the screen width check inside your directive.

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
  ];

  $scope.numDisp = 3;

});

app.directive('resizable', function($window) {
  return function($scope) {
    $scope.initializeWindowSize = function() {
      $scope.windowHeight = $window.innerHeight;
      // do width check here, especially since you have $window object here already
      if($window.innerWidth < 641)
          $scope.numDisp = 3; // 
      else if($window.innerWidth > 640 && $window.innerWidth < 1025)
          $scope.numDisp = 5;
      else if($window.innerWidth > 1024)
          $scope.numDisp = 10;

      console.log($window.innerWidth, $scope.numDisp); // check console for right output

      return $scope.windowWidth = $window.innerWidth;
    };
    $scope.initializeWindowSize();
    return angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
      $scope.initializeWindowSize();
      return $scope.$apply();
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: I have tried what you said and tried to combine it with a resize directive but I can't seem to get it to work. I made a Plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qTMp1c5f5oDZISCdLc6M?p=preview) I can see the resize working but I can't seem to connect it to numDisp to get the box amounts changing.

Comment: This works Perfectly thank you! I have updated the Plunkr with the working code for those who may need it http://plnkr.co/edit/qTMp1c5f5oDZISCdLc6M?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

limitTo is a [angular filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) and when you set its variable the ng-repeat directive recompiles it's content (more about [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile))

you can also set a function:

```
ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:calcLimit()"
```

and just return what you need

```
  $scope.calcLimit = function(limit) {
    if (resolution >= 1024)
      return 10;
    else if (resolution >= 640)
      return 6;
    else
      return 3;
  };
```

[plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/uCWv2fu8nFElgYOBIp44?p=preview) have fun! =)

Comment: limit != break point, eg, I have 8 items which I want to display all of them.

Comment: not sure what you meant, sorry. could you explain please?

Comment: for instance, I have 8 items I want to make `<div class="style1">1,2,3,4</div><div class="style2">5,6,7,8</div>` by simple <br> won't apply the diff style.

Comment: In this case i would not use a filter, try ngClass instead. [plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/wvtXZMk8Z0J1wyBgorBT?p=preview) or if more complex, use ngIf